# Google Location api not displaying coordinates

Tags: java, android

I am using the Google play services to fetch the users current location and try to display it in a TextView but for some reason nothing is happening. None of logs are printing out and the activity still says "hello world" rather that the coordinates. The app complies and runs without errors as well.

edit: the location icon does show up at my notification panel for a few seconds if that helps.

```
package com.trypickups.googlelocationservices;

import android.location.Location;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener{
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private Location mLastLocation;
    private TextView location;
    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }
    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        buildGoogleApiClient();


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        final TextView mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.location);
        mTextView.setText("Latitude "+ String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude()) + " Longitude " + String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude()));
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.e("Alesti", connectionResult.toString());

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you forgot to call `mGoogleApiClient.connect()`, and you also never call `requestLocationUpdates()`.

Here is code that I have tested and it works:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private Location mLastLocation;
    private TextView locationText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        locationText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.location);

        buildGoogleApiClient();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
        }
    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        Toast.makeText(this,"buildGoogleApiClient",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"onConnected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(5000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);

        //mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(0.1F);

        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"onConnectionSuspended",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"onConnectionFailed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        //Set contents of your TextView here
        locationText.setText("lat: " + location.getLatitude() + " lon: " + location.getLongitude());

        //set last location member variable
        mLastLocation = location;

        Log.d("locationtesting", "accuracy: " + location.getAccuracy() + " lat: " + location.getLatitude() + " lon: " + location.getLongitude());

        Toast.makeText(this,"Location Changed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is for getting multiple location updates 10 seconds apart.  use `mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);` instead

Comment: @doubleA IMO, the `getLastLocation()` method is pretty much useless.  It has a high tendency to return null, and even if it returns a valid Location, it could be very old and out-dated.  The problem is that this method does not actually request a new location lock.  Even if you just need one location update, the best way is to just register the listener, and then un-register in `onLocationChanged()` once the first callback comes in.  This way you are guaranteed to get the current location.

Comment: You are right it returns null if your ApiClient is the first to connect to it and it is the first thing that you call. `getLastLocation()` is a best effort thing. for simplicity in a simple app use `getLastLocation()` If you Require a recent location update then your only option is to register for the update.

Comment: How would I get the latitude and longitude from your block of code?

Comment: @Alex, take a look at the log entry in `onLocationChanged()`, it logs the latitude and longitude from the Location object returned in the callback.  Also, once you get one callback and set `mLastLocation`, you can then use `mLocation.getLatitude()` and `mLocation.getLongitude()`

Answer (score -1):

```
public class LocationFragment extends Fragment implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
private static final String TAG = LocationListFragment.class.getSimpleName();

private Location mLastLocation;

/**
 * Provides the entry point to Google Play services.
 */
protected GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

private FloatingActionButton fab;

private boolean mIsConnected = false;

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
     fab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     mIsConnected = true;
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    fab.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    mIsConnected = false;
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

/**
 * Mandatory empty constructor for the fragment manager to instantiate the
 * fragment (e.g. upon screen orientation changes).
 */
public LocationFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container, false);
    fab = (FloatingActionButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getLastLocation();
        }
    });

    buildGoogleApiClient();
    return rootView;
}

private void getLastLocation() {
    if(mIsConnected) {
        mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        if(mLastLocation != null) {
            //TODO: do something with the location.
        }
    }

}

protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
}


@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null)
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
}
}
```

an example of using the fused location provider to get the last location. This is from an example of GoogleMaps with material design elements. The fragment gets last location when the floating action button is clicked. Keep in mind what @Daniel Nugent mentioned about the reliability of the `getLastLocation()` call. While i do not think it is useless it does have its limitations. For realtime updates register for them like Daniel Nugent's answer. [GitHub Link to above code](https://github.com/px-amaac/MapsMaterialLecture/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/coding/doublea/mapsmateriallecture/LocationListFragment.java)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @piet.t You are right The answer has been edited and I removed the code that didn't relate to the question at hand.